# Unable to put Sails.js app in production

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

I'm trying to put my app into production with Sails.js, but cannot get past the grunt tasks. This is the error I'm receiving:

```
error: Error: The hook `grunt` is taking too long to load.
Make sure it is triggering its `initialize()` callback, or else set 
`sails.config.grunt._hookTimeout to a higher value (currently 20000)
at tooLong [as _onTimeout] 
   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:92:21)
   at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
```

I have increased `sails.config.grunt._hookTimeout` dramatically and still the process hasn't been completed. Running a `sails debug` in either production or development outputs:

```
Grunt :: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
   at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
   at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
   at listen (net.js:1182:10)
   at Agent.Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
   at Object.start (_debugger_agent.js:20:9)
   at startup (node.js:86:9)
   at node.js:814:3
```

I find it very strange that in development mode everything works fine, but its not the case in production. The files included are pretty big, such as angular, moment and other modules. This is how the `jsFilesToInject` looks:

```
var jsFilesToInject = [

 // Load sails.io before everything else
 'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',

 'js/dependencies/angular.min.js',
 'js/dependencies/moment.min.js',
 'js/dependencies/angular-ui-router.min.js',
 'js/dependencies/angular-sails.min.js',
 'js/dependencies/angular-moment.min.js',
 'js/dependencies/angular-animate.min.js',
 'js/dependencies/angular-aria.min.js',
 'js/dependencies/angular-material.min.js',

 // All of the rest of your client-side js files
 // will be injected here in no particular order.
 'js/**/*.js'

];
```

I'm not sure what else would be causing this, any suggestions? I'm using Sails version 0.11.0

Comment: What port are you using for production? If it's port 80,  see if there are other services using it already (nginx, apache, etc.) and kill them. Also worth trying to lift sails as root to find if it's a permission-related hitch.

Comment: I'm running as root and its on port 443 for SSL. Although it wasn't working on 80 anyway. No apache or nginx installed.

Comment: try running grunt uglify:dist by itself

Comment: Try running it in port 1337, probably you are already using defaults ports

Answer (score 7):

I just had this same problem and it was just that the timeout was not big enough I had to put this in my config/local.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    hookTimeout: 120000
};
```

Comment: Coming back to this after a year, I would say that you should run grunt or grunt buildProd with a --verbose flag to see why this is taking so long to run. It can also be that something else is already running on that port. You can do a sails lift --port=1234 to test on another port

Answer (score 1):

I just posted the same issue on github, and then checked out the source code. So I read through the grunt hook to understand what happens. And it turns out that in `default` mode the grunt hook triggers the callback right after grunt has started, but for the `prod` mode it is triggered only when grunt has finished all the tasks.

There is a following comment in the source code:

> cb - optional, fires when the Grunt task has been started (non-production) or finished (production)

So if there is anything watching (like using `watch` in browserify) in `prod`, grunt task will never exit, and therefore grunt hook will always timeout. But even if nothing is watching, starting the grunt task takes much longer that finishing all the tasks, and this explains why we don't see the problem when not in production mode.
Since modifying the original grunt hook is not the best idea (it lives in `node_modules`), the best is indeed to increase (possibly dramatically) the `_hookTimeout` option and to make sure grunt task exits (for this it can be run separately with `grunt prod`).